# What is the difference between android:persistent vs Service.START_STICKY?

Tags: android, service, android-service, persistence

This [blog](https://medium.com/tassio-auad-developer/service-restart-behavior-compilation-3309446e962e) clearly explained the difference between

- Service.START_STICKY
- Service.START_NOT_STICKY
- Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT

Now after reading this I got confused when seeing this service declaration with AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service android:name="com.amazon.tablet.myapplication.MyService" android:persistent="true"></service>
```

I assumed/understood so far that making `android:persistent=true` in service declaration would turn the service to persistent and restart when it goes down. But I'm able to achieve this without having `persistent=true` with `Service.START_STICKY` alone.

1. What's the difference between `android:persistent=true` vs these attributes `Service.START_STICKY`, `Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT`?
2. When the service is recreated will the app be relaunched again? I'm trying to understand will the process for the application be created when the service recreated.

   Note : I declared the service with property `android:persistent=true` and tried killing my app with `adb shell kill <pid>` but it's recreated. I'm wondering / not understanding the difference between making the service recreation vs application recreation in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Service.START_STICKY**

This would wait for the intent to start the service (once the process associated with this gets killed)

**2. android:persistent="true"**

This would make the service as persistent true/false accordingly and this doesn't wait for the intent to make the service up again (once it gets killed due to LMK and all)

**3. Service vs Application persistent**

By making the service persistent this would make the process associated with it as persistent. And the same case with application.

When you declare a separate process for your service then your app would not be persistent.